# Como copiar de un array nombres aleatoriamente hacia otro array

Tags: java

En un método tengo 2 parámetros uno es el tamaño y otro el `array` simplemente si el tamaño es menor que el `array`

- Poner en cada posición de ese `array` (res) un nombre, seleccionado aleatoriamente de entre todos los nombres del `array` (orig).

Os dejo el código que no consigo hacer que se copie aleatoriamente

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
        int numeroResultado;
        numeroResultado=4;
     String nombre []={"pepe","antonio","hola","juanito"};
     subArray(numeroResultado,nombre);

        for (int i = 0; i < nombre.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("El nombre es "+nombre[i]);
        }
       pideNumeroPositivo(numeroResultado);
    }
    public static int pideNumeroPositivo (int maximo){
        Scanner sca=new Scanner (System.in);
            int numeroPedido;
        do{
            System.out.println("Dime un numero asegurate que sea menor que "+maximo);
            numeroPedido=Integer.parseInt(sca.nextLine());
            //Preguntar como se hace while o por que no funciona con && y si con ||
       }while(numeroPedido<0||numeroPedido>maximo);

        return numeroPedido;
    }
    public static String[] subArray (int tamaño,String[] orig ){
      int  i=0;
      int rango=4;
        if (tamaño>orig.length) {
            return null;
        }else if (tamaño<=orig.length) {
            String res[]=new String[tamaño];
            res [i]=(int)(Math.random()*orig);
            return res;
        }
      return orig;  
    }
}
```

Me ha costado la vida pero al final lo he hecho así:
Supongo que los nombres así no se podrán repetir no?

```
 public static String[] subArray (int tamaño,String[] orig ){
  Random aleatorio=new Random();
  int valorDado = aleatorio.nextInt(3)+1;
    if (tamaño>orig.length) {
        return null;
    }else if (tamaño<=orig.length) {
        String res[]=new String[tamaño];
        for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            res[i]=orig[valorDado];
            valorDado=valorDado+1;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <res.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(res[j]);
        }
            return res;  
    }
  return orig;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay una forma simple de hacer esto que consistiría en:

1. Ordenar el array original de forma aleatoria mediante `Collections.shuffle()`
2. Una vez establecido el orden aleatorio, extraer de él únicamente los `N` elementos requeridos en el nuevo array mediante `Arrays.copyOfRange()`

La desventaja aquí es que el array original quedaría modificado y, si lo necesitas en su orden original para otras cosas esta opción no es viable.

De todos modos, lo dejo aquí como posible solución simple en casos de que el estado final del array original pueda quedar modificado.

Otra cosa es que tienes que evaluar también que `maxSize` sea mayor que `0`.

Este sería el método. He simplificado el código, declarando el array final al principio como `null`. De ese modo evitamos el `else` y usar dos `return`. He evitado también usar `ñ` en las variables, optando por una convención de nombre en inglés.

```
public static String[] subArray (int maxSize,String[] srcArray ){
    String[] newArray=null;
    if ( maxSize > 0 && maxSize <= srcArray.length ) {
        /*Ordenamos el array original de forma aleatoria*/
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(srcArray));
        /*Creamos el nuevo array extrayendo únicamente maxSize elementos*/
        newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(srcArray, 0, maxSize);
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

### Ejemplos:

```
    int maxSize=3;
    String nombre []={"pepe","antonio","hola","juanito"};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subArray(maxSize,nombre)));
```

**Salida:**

```
[hola, antonio, pepe]
```

---

```
    int maxSize=4;
    String nombre []={"pepe","antonio","hola","juanito"};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subArray(maxSize,nombre)));
```

**Salida:**

```
[hola, juanito, pepe, antonio]
```

---

```
    int maxSize=7;
    String nombre []={"pepe","antonio","hola","juanito"};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subArray(maxSize,nombre)));
```

**Salida:**

```
null
```

Answer (score 1):

El principal problema es que necesitas generar los nombres aleatorios "tamaño" veces y en tu código se hace solo una vez.

El segundo problema (que deriva del primero) es que al ejecutar random pueden salir valores repetidos. Por lo tanto antes de agregar el nuevo elemento tenés que verificar que el elemento no haya sido agregado con anterioridad. Esto sería mucho mas simple usando objetos de la clase collection como ArrayList o LinkedList. Con arrays es un poco más artesanal.

En el código más abajo se usa un metodo inArray() para determinar si el valor existe en un array. Y el método mostrar() que simplemente imprime el contenido de array.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomStrings{
     Random random = new Random();

     public static void main(String []args){
        RandomStrings randomStrings= new RandomStrings();
        randomStrings.run(args);
     }

     public void run(String [] args) {
        int numeroResultado = 4;
        String nombres []={"pepe","antonio","hola","juanito"};
        mostrar(nombres);
        String [] nombresRandom = subArray(numeroResultado,nombres);
        mostrar(nombresRandom);
     } 

     public String[] subArray (int tamaño,String[] orig ){
        String [] rtn = new String[tamaño];
        int  i=0;
        if (tamaño > orig.length) {
            rtn = null;
        } else {
           while (i < tamaño) {
              String prox  = orig[random.nextInt(orig.length)];
              if (!inArray(prox, rtn)) {
                  rtn[i++] = prox;
              }
           }
        }
        return rtn;  
     }

     public boolean inArray(String elemento, String [] array) {
         for (String str : array) {
             if (str != null && str.equals(elemento)) {
                return true; 
             }
         }
         return false;
     }

     public void mostrar(String [] arr) {
         for (String str : arr) {
             System.out.println(str);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: no he dado el metodo inArray no hay otra forma de hacer aunque no se use random que sea mas sencilla?

Comment: el método lo escribí yo está en el código más abajo.